# Dynamic Sites with Wordpress (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

Hey I'm slightly newb when it comes to building comment boxes and avatar/profile pic systems linking with acccounts

My question is: Is there a way I can just use parts of Wordpress CMS such as the content system (because it is* separate via comments.php) into my dynamic php/sql driven website?

Are there any examples of this? I've been having a hard time finding any examples/tutorials/github stuff on this

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress wouldn't really be something you could pick apart like that, most of the components are tied together and I don't think it would be easy to use just the cms part and not others.  The admin interface would definitely be hard to change, and since wordpress updates frequently, you would have trouble merging the updates back to your site I would think.

That said, you can find or create a custom theme and disable comments and remove all the comment functionality from your site.  If not, can you describe your needs more and/or what you already have done?  Maybe another CMS or system would be more suitable for you.

Or look at one of the PHP frameworks such as [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com), [symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org), or [Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com).  These frameworks can ease development but have some learning curve.